# Google AutomML Object Detection Missing Core ML Export

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, automl

I created an Object Detection model using Google AutoML. I'd like to export the model to Core ML but on the export page this option isn't showing up. I can't find anything in the [AutoML Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/export-edge) about when this export option is disabled.[image: Export page]

Additionally, if I try to export from the command line I get the error message `Unsupported model export format [core_ml] for model`.

Can someone provide some clarity about why this isn't an option? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with a confusion between [automl vision documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/export-edge) that focuses on classification models and specific automl vision [object detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/export-edge) model documentation. In [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/overview/docs#automl-vision) index you can see all those docs.

As you can see in the links, for the specific case of object detection models there is no option to export to Core ML.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's a bummer that it isn't supported but I'm glad it's not just me!